# Error while passing String in two classes JavaFX

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx-2, javafx, parameter-passing

I am getting a NullPointerException while passing String from one class to a function in other class. I don't exactly understand what is wrong. I also to tried to make sure if the String I am passing is null or not. But it isn't Null..

The line where the Exception is pointing out and where the Function in the AMCHelpEditor is called is below(The error in this code is in last line : 125 of the original code):

```
String s = AMCImage.getSmellFromAMC(file);
System.out.print(s);
System.out.print(s.isEmpty());
System.out.print(SMCImage.getSmellFromAMC(f));
GridPane grid = sm.AMCEdit(s);
```

Also, the function code of AMCEdit in the AMCEditor is:

```
public GridPane AMCEdit(String s){
  amc = am.readAllAmcName();
  AMCBean sb2 = new AMCBean();
  AMCAccessor sa = new AMCAccessor();
  sb2 = sa.getAllAmcInfoById(s); 
  String name = sb2.getAmcName();
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 20, 20));
    gridPane.setHgap(7); gridPane.setVgap(7);

    Label amc1 = new Label("Select AMC :");
    GridPane.setHalignment(smell1, HPos.RIGHT);


    cb = new ChoiceBox();
    cb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(amc));
    cb.getSelectionModel().select(name);



    cb.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
         @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue,
            Object newValue) {
            text =cb.getValue().toString();
            xyz = sm.getAllAmcInfoByName(text);
             descptn = xyz.getAmcDesc().toString();
             frmla = xyz.getAmcChemFormula().toString();
             am = xyz.getAmcId();
             setAmc(am);
             tfdesc = new TextField(descptn);          
             tffrml = new TextField(frmla);
            }
    });


     gridPane.add(amc1, 0, 0);
     gridPane.add(cb, 1, 0);

      gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(
        new ColumnConstraints(150),
        new ColumnConstraints(200)
    );
            gridPane.getRowConstraints().addAll(
           new RowConstraints(30),
           new RowConstraints(), // scale
           new RowConstraints(30),
           new RowConstraints(),
           new RowConstraints(30),
           new RowConstraints(),
           new RowConstraints(30)

     );

     return gridPane;

}
```

The error shown as system output is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.smell.component.AMCEditor.AMCEdit(AMCEditor.java:125)
    at com.smell.component.AMCHelpEditor.getTab(AMCHelpEditor.java:74)
    at com.smell.modules.ImageApi$1$1$1.handle(ImageApi.java:100)
    at com.smell.modules.ImageApi$1$1$1.handle(ImageApi.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3324)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
'201''201'false'201'Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" jfxsa-run:
```

The systems outputs are as expected.(Refer the last lines of the error). If the Strings are not Null then

Could you please point out the error or suggest an alternative to it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the that rather than checking the string for null, put a null check for your sm object

sm.AMCEdit(s);

Here your sm object might not have been initialized and then trying to invoke a method on uninitialized sm will result in NPE

So make sure you have initialzed it.

Comment: the sm object is never null.. and it is always intialized.. I checked for it by debuging as well...